# HERE API Traffic Flow 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, here-api, here-traffic

I try requesting traffic flow data

```
page = requests.get('https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.2/flow.xml?apiKey={}&bbox={},{};{},{}&responseattributes=sh,fc'.format(api_key,north,west,south,east))
print(page.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

but the response is

```html
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

It was working fine yesterday though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently their services is down right now. Can check the status here

https://support.here.com/status

Answer (score 0):

There was a temporary outage happened for which you faced this issue.
The problem was resolved and corrective measures have been taken for it's prevention.